# Vue.js 2 how to access data in method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using single file components triggered from vue-router. I have a `components/Header.vue` which uses a child `modals/HelpModal.vue` which in turn has a child `components/Modal.vue`.

I'm trying to pass around events in order to keep `Modal.vue` re-usable, but I can't seem to access `this.show` from within an event in `HelpModal.vue`

Modal.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="modal">
        <button class="modal__close" @click="$emit('close')">
        </button>

        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

HelpModal.vue

```
<template>
    <modal v-if="show" @close="closeModal">...help modal content...</modal>
</template>

<script>
import Modal from 'components/Modal.vue'
import bus from 'eventBus'

export default {

    components: {
        Modal
    },

    data: () => {
        return {
            show: false
        }
    },

    methods: {
        closeModal: () => {
            this.show = false
        }
    },

    mounted: () => {
        bus.$on('showHelpModal', () => {
            console.log('show modal!', this.show); // undefined
            this.show = true
        })
    }
}
```

Header.vue

```
<template>
    <header>
        <button @click="showHelpModal">Show help</button>
        <help-modal></help-modal>
    </header>
</template>

<script>
    import HelpModal from 'views/modals/HelpModal.vue'
    import bus from 'eventBus'

    export default {

        components: {
            HelpModal
        },

        methods: {
            showHelpModal: () => {
                bus.$emit('showHelpModal')
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I may be going about this all totally wrong, but it's the only way I can see it working to have a link in the header that triggers the help modal to open

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Don't use arrow functions to define your methods](https://rainsoft.io/when-not-to-use-arrow-functions-in-javascript/). At execution `this` will be wrong, because arrow functions preserve the `this` (also called context) from the time of their definition. Methods are defined as part of the component definition process, so the component is not the context when the method is being defined.

An ordinary `function` definition will determine context based on how it is called, so `component.method()` will have `component` as its context, which is what you want.

If your method doesn't reference `this`, you *can* use arrow functions, but I recommend against it, because there will come times that you update the definition, use `this`, and it will bite you.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
data() {
    return {
        show: false
    }
},
```

This is how I use my data for my components.